# Как в Guard'е задать параметры, чтоб потом прочитать в контроллере?

Tags: typescript, jwt, nestjs

Есть Гуард, который проверяет токен:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    canActivate(
        context: ExecutionContext,
    ): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
        const request: Request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();

        const token = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken()(request);

        try {
            const payload = JwtService.getPayload(token);
            // тут нужно в реквест прокинуть payload 
        }
        catch (e) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Ну и контроллер:

```
@Post('/v1/saves')
@UseGuards(AuthGuard)
async savesSave(@Body(new ValidationPipe({transform: true})) saveData) {
   // как здесь прочитать то, что установил в Guard'е?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пока только такое по-быстрому сделал:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    canActivate(
        context: ExecutionContext,
    ): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
        const request: Request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();

        const token = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken()(request);

        try {
            const payload = JwtService.getPayload(token);
            request["payload"] = JwtService.getPayload(token); // <--- грязнота
        }
        catch (e) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Декоратор:

```
import {createParamDecorator} from '@nestjs/common';

export const UserPayload = createParamDecorator((data, req) => {
    return req.payload;
});
```

Тогда контроллер таким становится:

```
@Post('/v1/saves')
@UseGuards(AuthGuard)
async savesSave(@Body(new ValidationPipe({transform: true})) saveData, @UserPayload() payload: JwtPayload) {
}
```

Но вот `request["payload"]` выглядит некрасиво =\